# How to save image extracted from com.android.contacts, Android?

Tags: android

I extracted photo URL from  contacts list and got following path:

```
content://com.android.contacts/contacts/1237/photo
```

Before to upload to javascript (I use Cordova) I want to get image and save it as `png` file in local storage.

This is what I did so far:

```
private void savefile(String name, String path){        

   File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myApp/images/");

   File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myApp/images/"+name+".png");


              if(!direct.exists()){
                  direct.mkdir();
              }


              if (!file.exists()) {
                      try {
                          file.createNewFile();
                          FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(path).getChannel(); // <- here I get Exception
                          FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(file).getChannel();
                          dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                          src.close();
                          dst.close();

                      } catch (IOException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      }
              }
  }
```

But I get file not found Exception

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, gotFileEntryMessage, fsFailMessage);

function gotFileEntryMessage(fileEntry) {

     var Path = fileEntry.fullPath;
    alert(Path);
  }

  function fsFailMessage(error) {
    console.log("failed with error code: " + error.code);
  }
```

> This thing will give you the path of file which is stored in your phone memory and pass this to your Java method using Cordova Plugin.